# Anchor doesn't work in chrome and safari browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a problem: an html anchor doesn't work in chrome and safari. The page goes down instead of up.
I have this HTML:

```
<a id="to-top"></a>
<a class="button toTop" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('to-top').scrollIntoView(true);return false;">Вверх</a>
```

And this JavaScript code:

```
var topScreen = window.pageYOffset ? window.pageYOffset : document.body.scrollTop;
        var myScreen = screen.availHeight;
        if(topScreen > (myScreen / 3)) {
            $(".toTop").fadeTo(0, 1.0);
        }
        else {
            $(".toTop").fadeTo(0, 0);
```

SCSS:

```
.toTop {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 20px;
        right: 20px;
        z-index: 999999;
        transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
        outline: none;
        &:hover {
            transition-delay:0s;
        }
        a {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            &:hover {
                color: #000;
            }
        }
    }
```

What is wrong? Besides, this element stays focused after click.

Comment: Some of your Javascript appears to be missing?

Comment: Provide a fiddle with have problems like you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, since you have not set up a JSFiddle, it's difficult for us to exactly figure out what is happening in your project and what is expected. However, I have made a [small fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8Lzvxbh/) that, I think, solves your problem.

**HTML**

```
<div id="to-top"></div>
<a class="button toTop" href="#to-top">Вверх</a>
```

**CSS**

```
#to-top {
    height: 200vh;
}
```

The problem in your project is probably that you are trying to jump to another `<a>`-tag, while the anchor-jump only seems to work with `div`s that contain an `id`. Please try the fiddle I've added and see if changing the element of `to-top` to `div` works for you.

In the future, you should really add your own fiddle to a question though.

Comment: Thanks. It really solved a problem. 
Further I will follow your advice, I will add fiddle for questions.